# TypeScript Generic infer based on field

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

```
enum Letter {
  A = "A",
  B = "B",
  C = "C"
}

export type EntityT<T extends Letter = Letter> = T extends Letter.A
  ? { a: number }
  : T extends Letter.B
  ? { b: string }
  : T extends Letter.C
  ? { c: string }
  : never;

type DeltaT<T extends EntityT> = _DeltaT<T, keyof T>;

export type _DeltaT<E extends EntityT, K extends keyof E> = {
  key: K;
  oldValue: E[K];
  newValue: E[K];
};

export type ProblemT<T extends Letter = Letter> = EntityT<T> extends infer E
  ? {
      id: string;
      type: T;
      delta: DeltaT<E>[];
      oldEntity: E;
      newEntity: E;
    }
  : never;

const testCase: ProblemT<Letter.A> = {
  id: "id",
  type: Letter.A,
  delta: [{ key: "a", oldValue: 1, newValue: 2 }],
  oldEntity: { a: 1 },
  newEntity: { a: 2 }
};

function myFunc<T extends Letter>(e: ProblemT<T>) {
  switch (e.type) {
    case Letter.A: {
      const uselessConversion = e as ProblemT<Letter.A>;
      return uselessConversion.newEntity.a;
    }
    case Letter.B: {
      const uselessConversion = e as ProblemT<Letter.B>;
      return uselessConversion.newEntity.b;
    }
    case Letter.C: {
      const uselessConversion = e as ProblemT<Letter.C>;
      return uselessConversion.newEntity.c;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to declare a type `ProblemT` that depends on his `type` key, will return different values in `oldEntity` and `newEntity`.
I want to run `myFunc` with the switch without the need to convert the object manually, and TypeScript will infer the type based on the `type` property. But it does not work well.
How to make the switch infer the type automatically without the need to convert.
Is there a better way to declare the `ProblemT` differently type so the switch can infer it?

Here is a link to the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/KYOwrgtgBAMsAu9gCcoG8BQUoEEoF4oAiHIgGiygCEDirzKBhWoxojAXww2AA8AHAPbJ4UeAE9+wKAFEQ8AJYSAKgB5lUPkhAATAM6wESVITiIUAPloatofYfPIAdDkoB+dFACGALijgIACMUKC5sPxtebXszYycqd09Avz14ZAUQAHNQygjNKLsDWJQnRkS0KABjFLSM7LCoPxBgADcUAG5uCSkoABFgABt4LzVI6IM5RRUrQgB9fqGR9TIoAGtgcUEAMyhlC06eAWFRbul5weG1GXzx2XklcWUVgGkbwrWN7dkZ9Ep18T8z062EEAx0ADUvAMwMA-DIANrPAC6wP8wAA7pDobDZIiUZwDnwhCIxJJpAAFZCCQIDYAQUZvXRFIwhUws5A-SYPUZWWxMqAZLYhGTlSjYbAKHQ1dJZVHi0lSCJy8U6C6+Ppqq4WeH4+UgsFciRw5XYZrow0A2TKhpNVodbiVQQgVJiYCpRhePQ4ynU2n01TFZw4H6YCVS4iShjYU5+QMuCjYVWLPzwir-PxELzkKCgiFQmF+ACMKzNWILUAATKEkQmcwb7kbPOrC6Fa2aLX4Kuqq1wOActmAQJVFE6oBBxAAxQeVdSMmLsiwACm9VJpdJ5AEpftg9OilJUABZQZdOU5b0Piyqe6RxnCdsWXp0usBe2l6PSMJ1tZB6BSjwjSJ6UA+mu-q3vsD7YMgCBgMgIBQC+gxuh+X4oL+TpOO2DbiE4XjWg+V5eg4cRUPeepVE+oiIW+KEgN+6HwQB3gGCBfpqHGVAQeR0HwLB8HUchn50Whf4gJhGIWk4gT4fKhE3uypRkXqjrOlRr6CahP6ibQgEsaubEBgpjBcXqPF8Qh6nvkJ9GieJ5rYU4lQyTkHBAA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that types such as `Letter.A | Letter.B` also extends `Letter`, so the compiler does not know that things are as constrained as they are.

Something like this will work:

```js
enum Letter {
  A = "A",
  B = "B",
  C = "C"
}

export type EntityT<T extends Letter> =
  T extends Letter.A ? { a: number }
  : T extends Letter.B ? { b: string }
  : T extends Letter.C ? { c: string }
  : never;

export type DeltaT<T extends Letter, K = keyof EntityT<T>> = K extends keyof EntityT<T>
  ? {
    key: K;
    oldValue: EntityT<T>[K];
    newValue: EntityT<T>[K];
  }
  : never;

export type ProblemT<T extends Letter> = {
  id: string;
  type: T;
  delta: DeltaT<T>[];
  oldEntity: EntityT<T>;
  newEntity: EntityT<T>;
};

function myFunc(e: ProblemT<Letter.A> | ProblemT<Letter.B> | ProblemT<Letter.C>) {
  switch (e.type) {
    case Letter.A: return e.newEntity.a;
    case Letter.B: return e.newEntity.b;
    case Letter.C: return e.newEntity.c;
  }
}
```